# How can I enable spring boot 1.2.5, using jersey, to print the raw http request and response to the console?

Tags: http, logging, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

I have a spring boot 1.2.5 service that uses jersey 2. I see the requests in my own logs but I'd like to see the raw http request and response in the console as well. How can you turn on printing http traffic to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JerseyConfiguration.class.getName());

    public JerseyConfiguration() {
        ...

        register(new LoggingFilter(log, true));
    }
}
```